# Hash mathemetical operations

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to do a mathematical operation with this hash value for example:;

```
hash = {"Num"=>4}
hash["Num"] = hash["Num"-1]
```

P.S 
I know that that would result to an error so please tell what is the correct way.

Comment: What is that you want to do? We can only what the correct way to achieve what you want is, if you tell what it is that you want to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to subtract one from a value in a hash:

```
hash["Num"] -= 1
```

When you put `hash["Num"-1]` that tries to evaluate `"Num"-1` which isn't valid, you can't subtract a number from a string.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If this solves your problem don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. This helps steer others in the same situation towards a solution.